# Empty array after passing array by reference to array_walk()

Tags: php, arrays, reference, traversal

I have made this little class:

```
class Analyzer {
    public static function analyze($phrases) {
        $sortedPhrases = array();
        array_walk($phrases, array('self', 'splitByLength'), $sortedPhrases);
        var_dump($sortedPhrases);
    }

    private static function splitByLength($item, $key, &$resArr) {
        // line stolen from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4786840/603003
        // thanks to arnaud576875 <http://stackoverflow.com/users/576875/arnaud576875>
        $len = count( preg_split('#\PL+#u', $item, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );
        if (!isset($resArr[$len])) {
            $resArr[$len] = array();
        }
        $resArr[$len][] = $item;

        var_dump($resArr);
    }
}

$phrases = array(
    "I can't believe the great content",
    "I can't understand the superior information",
    "I can't comprehend the amazing data",
    "I cannot analyze the amazing data",
    "I haven't written to the amazing data"
);
Analyzer::analyze($phrases);
```

Executing the script results in the output below:

```
array (size=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'I can't believe the great content' (length=33)

...

array (size=3)
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'I can't believe the great content' (length=33)
      1 => string 'I can't understand the superior information' (length=43)
      2 => string 'I can't comprehend the amazing data' (length=35)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'I cannot analyze the amazing data' (length=33)
  8 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'I haven't written to the amazing data' (length=37)

array (size=0)
  empty
```

All outputs are actually correct except the last one which comes from *Analyzer::analyze()*. It seems that the variable `$sortedPhrases` is somehow cleared after [array_walk()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

Comment: Make your private function public and test it on a specific data if it works you must not be passing the correctly value to your callback

Comment: @MichaelSole I get the same effect when using *splitByLength* outside the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a better look at [`array_walk`'s documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

> **userdata**
>
> *If the optional userdata parameter is supplied, it will be passed as
>   the third parameter to the callback funcname.*

That's the third parameter. It's not a reference, it's just a value that gets passed to your callback function.

---

One (of many) solutions to your problem is to use an object instead (objects are always passed by reference):

```
class Analyzer {
    public static function analyze($phrases) {
        $arrObj = new ArrayObject();
        array_walk($phrases, array('self', 'splitByLength'), $arrObj);
        var_dump($arrObj->getArrayCopy());
    }

    private static function splitByLength($item, $key, $arrObj) {
        // line stolen from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4786840/603003
        // thanks to arnaud576875 <http://stackoverflow.com/users/576875/arnaud576875>
        $len = count( preg_split('#\PL+#u', $item, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );
        if (!isset($arrObj[$len])) {
            $arrObj[$len] = array();
        }
        $arrObj[$len][] = $item;

        var_dump($arrObj->getArrayCopy());
    }
}
```

(it doesn't have to be an [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), it can be a stdClass object with an array property, or create your own class if you want...)

---

Or you can wrap your call within an anonymous function if you really want to work with a reference:

```
$static = get_called_class();
array_walk($phrases, function($item, $key) use($static, &$sortedPhrases){
  $static::splitByLength($item, $key, $sortedPhrases);
});
```

Comment: Hats off! I was fiddling with the code and reached the conclusion: the extra parameter passed to the map function could not be a reference. Didn't know about ArrayObject, very interesting. Another possible solution could be using a static member variable, but the ArrayObject solution is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now! But I'm still asking myself why the normal array does not lose its value while *walking* over the array. The last call to the callback function actually dumps (all correctly) gathered values. I think that it must has something to do with the internal implementation. (*You get your bounty in 23 hours ;).*)

Comment: Because the normal array is the first argument, which is a reference (notice the `&` the description in the docs)

Answer (score 2):

While the third argument sent to the callback function cannot be a reference itself, it can contain references.

A different approach (to using objects or wrapping your callback in a closure) is to pass an array to the callback, containing a reference to the variable you wish to update.  The wrapping array gets passed by-value, but all it contains is the referenced value that you want to change.

```
class Analyzer {
    public static function analyze($phrases) {
        // …
        array_walk($phrases,
                   array('self', 'splitByLength'),
                   array(&$sortedPhrases));
        // …
    }

    private static function splitByLength($item, $key, $extra_args) {
        $resArr = &$extra_args[0];
        // …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is wrong:

`array_walk($phrases, array('self', 'splitByLength'), $sortedPhrases);`

So, Try this:

`$sortedPhrases = array_walk($phrases, 'splitByLength');`

And return your values in `$sortedPhrases` and don't use pass by reference (personal thing)

Comment: PHP yields `array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback` because this is not a valid callback, of course.