# PHP count words BETTER than str_word_count

Tags: php, function, count, word-count

Since I read that str_word_count is flawed, I searched for an alternate solution and came across the following, which works quite good in general except of one problem.

```
function count_words($text) {

    //it removes html tags
    $text = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $text);

    //it removes html space code
    $text = preg_replace(array('/&nbsp;/'), ' ', $text);

    //it removes multiple spaces with single
    $text = trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $text));

    return count(explode(' ', $text));
}
```

The problem is that it detects a dash "-" as a word.

Example:

```
This is a title - Additional Info
```

It will count 7 words instead of 6.

Is there a possibility to exclude single characters like - from this word count?

Comment: Curious where you read that `str_word_count` is flawed.

Comment: I tested it myself on a larger text and it didn't give me the acurate word amount like Microsoft word for instance. And the flaws are also mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786802/how-to-count-the-words-in-a-specific-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just count words:

```
$count = preg_match_all("/[\w']+/", $text);
```

To get the functionality of removing HTML tags and HTML entities:

```
$count = preg_match_all("/[\w']+/", html_entity_decode(strip_tags($text), ENT_QUOTES));
```

Probably better is to include what you think makes up a word.  Add anything that is not covered by `\w`.  The `i` makes it case-insensitive:

```
$count = preg_match_all("/[a-z']+/i", html_entity_decode(strip_tags($text), ENT_QUOTES));
```

Comment: Good, thanks! Any way to let it count "don't" as one word instead of two?

Comment: Perfect. Is there a possibility to also exclude digits? :) The word count is for a translation, so that the human translator knows how many words there are to translate. Since digits/numbers don't need to be translated, I'd like to not count them as words.

Comment: Sorry. I don't really understand. Using only the last line counts almost all charachters. Or is it supposed to be used in combination with the line above? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry I deleted the `+` somehow.